# What would be the correct approach for a light AngularJS web-app

Tags: html, angularjs, mobile

I am building a very light Web-App using AngularJS, and i can't seem to find the correct approach as to how to organize it.

To explain it briefly, the App loads a list of objects after the user logs in, and when he choses an object it loads all the detail from that object.

The app (as I am currently building it) will only have to load short JSON text data, so I thought I could have a single page app in a single HTLM file, directed by a single controller who will handle all the data received from the server, and the different views would have been handled by using HTML snippets and AngularJS directives ng-show and ng-includ, like so :

```
<div ng-show="correctView" ng-include="login_snippet.html >

</div>

<div ng-show="correctView" ng-include="table-view_snippet.html >

</div>

<div ng-show="correctView" ng-include="detail_view_snippet.html >

</div>
```

The correctView string is changed by the controller to decide which view is to be showned.

Is this a reasonable approach ? I can't seem to find whick one would suit my App best; it doesn't seem to be the right thing to do because the previous button doesnt work with this method, which can't do.

So,

- Is there a way to make it so the previous page button would work ?
- If not, what would be the correct thing to do ?Is it possible to have several HTML files sharing the same controller ? Or can some controller send data to another ?

I only found examples of single page applications where only parts of the page is changed when the user interacts with it, and this can't do for mine.

Comment: why you are using ng_show,ng_include is it suppose to be ng-show,ng-include

Comment: typo while doing the example sorry

Comment: Can you clarify "I only found examples of single page applications where only parts of the page is changed when the user interacts with it, and this can't do for mine." please? To me, it looks like either $state or $route would work fine here. You can use a parent controller or a service as a data shuttle - you would need to determine which suits your application

Comment: I mean that I have to change the entire view each time the changes page. Its meant for a phone so I wan't affort to have big navbars and anyway it would not be relevant.   I'll lookup at your advice, thanks.